# WCF Rest kit is showing my internal server names in the /help page

Tags: wcf, rest, dns

I have a simple WCF Rest service using the latest MS Restful preview kit. Everything works fine, site works as expected. However when I go to my /help page as in http://services.acme.com/help what is being shown is --

UriTemplate                 http://serv17.acme.com/Service.svc/Ping/string={ping}
Method                          GET
Response Format      Xml
Response Schema    http://serv17.acme.com/Service.svc/help/Ping/response/schema
Response Example   http://serv17.acne.com/Service.svc/help/Ping/response/example

Why is the help showing my internal server name, http://serv17.acme.com/ instead of http://www.acme.com/?

Comment: Apparently this has something to do with my service being hosted by IIS 6. I'm using the Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost2Factory for my service. Looking at the source code in the REST kit, the html created above is actually an Atom feed. Backing into the code the uri's are created from the ListenUri property of the endpoint. Since IIS is in charge of the endpoints I doubt there is anything you can do other than compile your own version of Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.dll to override the behavior.